# Seamless authorisation for telegram web apps

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Will [seamless authorisation](https://telegram.org/blog/privacy-discussions-web-bots#meet-seamless-web-bots) that happens with login url button happen on web apps launched through [direct links](https://telegram.org/blog/privacy-discussions-web-bots#meet-seamless-web-bots)

This [Direct Link Web Apps](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#direct-link-web-apps) feature was introduced in Bot API 6.7

I tried opening the webapp which is a page with telegram login.
I am expecting seamless login into my webapp for user authentication.
not sure how to do it.